# Help with oneliner - create random files, rename to two-char filename, fill with random strings

Tags: shell-script, scripting, perl

Would anyone be so kind and point me on how to make an one-liner from this? Or maybe use sed/awk/xargs? Or Perl? Or just make it simpler

I have achieved this by searching stackexchange and editing few scripts, but I'd like to see how to make it like a pro.

I'm creating files with random text in it. I don't know how many files will be created, please explain:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc "\t\n [:alnum:]" | dd of=./filemaster bs=100000000 count=1 && split -b 50 -a 10 ./filemaster && rm ./filemaster
```

I'm listing those filenames to file fnames1.txt:

```
ls >> fnames1.txt
```

I'm generating filenames that I want to another file - fnames2.txt

```
list=echo {a..z} ; for c1 in $list ; do for c2 in $list ; do echo $c1$c2.ext; done; done >> fnames2.txt
```

I merge those files to one file with two columns:

```
paste fnames1.txt fnames2.txt | column -s $'\t' -t >> fn.txt
```

I'm changing filenames according to file with columns (errors there as there are more files created than filenames generated, how to change exactly this amount of filenames? - I know I can ignore errors with 2>/dev/null):

```
while read -r line; do mv $line; done < fn.txt
```

I'm moving files with extension I need to another dir:

```
mkdir files && mv ./*.ext ./files/ && cd files
```

I need to re-write those files as the content needs to be bigger:

```
for file in *; do < /dev/urandom tr -dc "\t\n [:alnum:]" | head -c1500 > "$file"; done
```

Could anyone point me to a better way, or make an one-liner from this? I'd really appreciate that, because I'm learning how to do one-liners.

Comment: You can create a one-liner out of `cmd1` and `cmd2`  by saying `cmd1 && cmd2`.

Comment: Your command `list=echo {a..z}` is broken in several ways.

Comment: To address the bigger question, though, it would help to know what you're really trying to do.  What do you want to do with random files that you can't do with `/dev/urandom` directly?  (And you may find [Evolution of a Programmer](http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html) to be interesting.)  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard can you please explain why it's broken? It works though. :p
I was trying to generate files, that will be named aa.xyz...zz.xyz with random strings ~1000-1500 bytes each.

Comment: No, that command does not work.  It will attempt to run the command `a` with 25 arguments (from `b` to `z`) and with the environment variable `list` defined with the value `echo`.  Expected result will be `-bash: a: command not found`.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. The actual command I used was:
`list=\`echo {a..z}\` ; for c1 in $list ; do for c2 in $list ; do echo $c1$c2.ext; done; done >> fnames.txt`
Dunno why it cut off the \`\` symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the my opinion, oneliner doesn't suitable here. It will be big and not readable, not convenient. The script is better. It can be converted to the function.

This script creates the **"files"** directory and puts all created files to there. The size of the each file is the same, but it can be changed, if needed. Files named like: `aa.ext  ab.ext  ac.ext`, etc.

**Usage:** `./create_random_files.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Number of files
file_nums=5
# The size of the each file in bytes
file_size=1500

# Creates the "files" directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p files

for i in {a..z}{a..z}; do
    # gets data from the /dev/urandom file and remove all unneeded characters
    # from it - all characters except "\t\n [:alnum:]".
    tr -dc "\t\n [:alnum:]" < /dev/urandom |
    # The "head" command takes specified amount of bytes and writes them to the 
    # needed file. 
    # The "files/${i}.ext" is the relative path to new files, which named 
    # like "aa.ext" and placed into the "files" directory
    head -c "$file_size" > "files/${i}.ext"

    # Iterations counter. It will stop "for" loop, when file_nums
    # will be equal to zero
    if !(( --file_nums )); then 
        break
    fi  
done
```